# Parse jSON Response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a file upload plugin for one of my sites and a callback function of the "Delete" option returns a jSON response that looks like this:

```
{"5425ba85c976a~2014-09-26_7-13-47.png":true}
```

How would I go about parsing this jSON response in jQuery to know if the value is true or false?

This is what my code looks like but it prints undefined when i log this

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {

    var fileName = $(this).attr('filename');
    $.ajax({
        url: "server/php/?action=DELETE&file="+fileName,
        type: 'GET',
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data.fileName);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show us how the html element looks like? would recommend the data attribute for this btw.

Comment: You need `object.keys()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.

Comment: To compare your case to the duplicate: just like the example wrongly does `something.foo` but really wants the property named "`bar`" (which is stored in `foo`), you're wrongly doing `data.fileName`, when you really want the property named "`542...47.png`", which is stored in `fileName`. Bracket notation is your friend here: where the example solution is `something[foo]`, yours is `data[fileName]`.

Comment: @apsillers shouldnt `console.log(data[fileName]);` work then? Returns undefined

Comment: @SBB Yes, it should. I assumed the value of `fileName` was the same as the property name in the response; is it not? Also, just to make sure, are you checking the value inside of the `success` function?

Comment: It is in fact, fileName like the example. That line is in the success callback of the ajax statement

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(Object.keys(data), fileName)`? Do the first element of the `Object.keys` array and the `fileName` value match?

Comment: you might need to trim the value of the attribute from the element: `var filename = $.trim($(this).attr('filename'));`. I would also run a console.log("is equal?", (filename == '5425ba85c976a~2014-09-26_7-13-47.png')), right after you define filename. It is possible that there is some difference between what you think you have and what is really defined.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do

```
data["5425ba85c976a~2014-09-26_7-13-47.png"]
```

instead of

```
console.log(data.fileName);
```

Comment: that would be the way to get an array value, not a json property.

Comment: @Razah [`works for both`](http://jsfiddle.net/8t3grt65/) :)

Comment: @Razah if you are trying to use the value of a variable you have to use []. If you use `data.fileName` it will look for a property on the object named "fileName". using the bracket notation will look for a value on the object of the value of the variable `fileName`.

Comment: yes you're absolutely right and i should think more before i comment ;)

Comment: Since the image name is dynamic, I did `console.log(data[fileName]);` but it returned undefined

Comment: if `data["5425ba85c976a~2014-09-26_7-13-47.png"]` works and `data[fileName]` doesnt. its high time u console log fileName and check whats in it

Comment: console.log(fileName) returns the name of the file where as console.log(data[fileName]) returns undefined

Comment: did `data["5425ba85c976a~2014-09-26_7-13-47.png"]` work when u tried?

Comment: see [`this fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ea0u2gyu/). it has the use case you have and works. Or i missed something?